# Server certificate verification by 802.1x client

Tags: wpa-supplicant

I am configuring my device(embedded Linux based) for performing 802.1x authentication over EAP-TLS. Here I have requirement to verify EKU of server certificate.

When I checked wpa_supplicant confirm file, I found tls_ext_cert_check option to perform this kind of check.
But this option is saying that this check will be performed by external application.

how can I register my external application( in my case I am thinking a shell script) with wps_supplicant to perform this verification.

I googled but didn’t find any appropriate response of my query